# Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, jboss

I am new to JBoss and working with JBoss 7.1.1. I am running the jboss from the command prompt, It is showing the following error.

```
JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: F:\XBash-Dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java

 JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modul
es.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.Class.desiredAssertionStatus0(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    <<no stack trace available>>

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Does anybody have any ideas, what is the cause for this error?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

My theory is that this error happens when there is a mismatch between the *java.exe* and the *JRE libraries*.

I got this error today launching an application from Eclipse. I had recently updated to JDK **1.7.0_45**. I updated the JDK path in Eclipse to the **u45** directory. However, Eclipse still had the **u25** jars listed in the **JRE system libraries** panel.

I fixed this problem by opening the **Edit JRE** dialog under **Preferences > Installed JREs** and clicking the **Restore Default** button. This caused Eclipse to update the **JRE system libraries** to the **u45** jars.

Comment: I ran into this as well, and just had to set my JAVA_HOME correctly.